# PROC OPTMODEL (SAS language)

Tags: sas, mathematical-optimization, data-modeling, constraint-programming

I'm trying to maximize the production of green leaf vegetables taking into account contraints like: environmental issues and self-sufficiency. So the code generate this errors, could you help me please to find a solution for these errors:

ERROR 22-322: Erreur de syntaxe ; l'une des valeurs suivantes est attendue : =, {.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

The code

```
/* Définition des données */
data LegumesVerts;
   input Demande ProductionLocale CO2ParUnite EauDisponible TerreDisponible CO2Max EauMax TerreMax;
   datalines;
15000 5000 0.2 200000 10000 3000 250000 12000
;
run;

proc print data=legumesverts;
run; 

/* Définition du modèle d'optimisation */
proc optmodel;

   /* Variables de décision */
   number Demande, ProductionLocale, CO2ParUnite, EauDisponible, TerreDisponible, CO2Max, EauMax, TerreMax;
   read data LegumesVerts into Demande ProductionLocale CO2ParUnite EauDisponible TerreDisponible CO2Max EauMax TerreMax;
   var ProductionLegumesVerts >= 0;

   /* Fonction objectif : Maximiser la production de légumes verts */
   maximize ProductionLegumesVerts;
 
 /* Contraintes environnementales */
   con ContrainteCO2: ProductionLegumesVerts * CO2ParUnite <= CO2Max;
   con ContrainteEau: ProductionLegumesVerts <= EauMax;
   con ContrainteTerre: ProductionLegumesVerts <= TerreMax;

   /* Contrainte d'autosuffisance alimentaire */
   con ContrainteAutosuffisance: ProductionLegumesVerts >= Demande;

   /* Résolution du modèle d'optimisation */
   solve;

   /* Affichage des résultats */
   print ProductionLegumesVerts;
```

Thank you

I'm expecting that there is an issue in parameters declaration so the maximize statment get this error

Comment: The error message should actually underline the place in the code where the syntax error was detected.

Comment: the error was detected just after the objective function (Maximize):               
                               
 90            maximize ProductionLegumesVerts;
                                              _
                                              22
                                              76
 ERROR 22-322: Erreur de syntaxe ; l'une des valeurs suivantes est attendue : =, {.  
 
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: I do not see a MAXIMIZE declaration statement in the documentation, but perhaps SAS is assuming you meant MAX?  The syntax of that clearly requires an equal sign and an expression to maximize.  `MAX name  { index-set }  = expression  SUFFIXES=( values ) ;`

Comment: The problem was solved, thank you